# Resolve value in C#/.net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to resolve values in a class structure using some xpath-style resolver?

Exampel in code:

```
string name = Order.Customer.Firstname;
```

What i would like to do is something like this:

```
string name = (string)X.Resolve(Order, "Customer.Firstname");
```

Is there a way to do this in C#/.net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

You could use Reflection to get out the properties and members of a type. Look at [the MSDN page for `Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx.) to get started.

That method would give you a `PropertyInfo` which you can use to query the datatype of the property and to get and set it's value.